# Embedded Child Component in React is Undefined

Tags: reactjs, components, parent

I have the following parent component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import _ from "lodash";

import  ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

class ParentComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
        };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      I'm at Parent
       <ChildComponent/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {    }
 }


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ParentComponent);
```

Inside the parent has a component called ChildComponent that looks like this:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      at the child
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {      
    },
    dispatch
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  ChildComponent
);
```

When I try adding the child component I keep getting this error: [image]

But if I click continue the page turns back to normal. I don't understand how the child component is undefined. It's just embedded and does not include any props.

UPDATE:
I'm not getting the error anymore but I notice my page turns blank when I open this particular component. I'll be doing a bit more troubleshooting.

Comment: change `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  ChildComponent
); ` to `export default ChildComponent` and see if the problem still persists. Also, it will be easier to recreate the problem in a simple repo, fiddle, codepen or codesandbox so we can easily debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code, and it works fine for me. My thought was maybe what your entry file looks like? or file structure? If you like you can try the following syntax for the parent and child - it worked this way as well:

Child:

```
const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {}
}

const ConnectedChildComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {})(ChildComponent)

export default ConnectedChildComponent;
```

Parent:

```
const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {}
}

const ConnectedParentComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {})(ParentComponent)

export default ConnectedParentComponent;
```

Comment: I tried this and my result is the same. Thanks for the suggestion tho!

Answer (score 0):

In your ParentComponent change:

```
import  ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";
```

to

```
import  ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent.jsx";
```

i.e. add the missing ".jsx" extension. Your code is most likely determining the import to be a ".js" file by default, whereas it's actually a ".jsx" file.

Comment: interesting, my files are all .js so it might be something else

Comment: I previously encountered an issue like you are having, and for me it was because my WebPack set-up needed to be able to distinguish between js and jsx files.

Comment: I see. I did a fresh npm install of my package and the popup error seems to have gone, but my page goes blank a few seconds. I guess i'll keep debugging until it pops up again. Thanks!